# How to filter one column in Excel Pivot table

Tags: excel, pivot-table, spreadsheet, excel-pivot

I am trying to create a tunnel chart using data from Pivot table. However, I can't find a way to set a condition for one column ("Response Received Column). I want the table to count 5 people, and show 3 people responded. If I do the regular filter, I will only show 3 people on the "Name" column.

[image: Pivot Table]

Comment: why not create an additional column having either 0/1 or TRUE/FALSE as values against existing `response received column`?

Comment: Are you open to use power-pivot?

Comment: Yes, I am open to use power-pivot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Power-pivot** solution.  can be replicated directly in excel too.

Adding data to model, create an additional column say `positive response` with calculation as

```
=IF(Table1[response_received]="Yes", 1,0)
```

[image]

Click `pivot table` in first menu tab, and get your desired view like this

[image]

**Note** that I have used sum instead of count here.

Answer (score 0):

You can use array formulas - like this.
In the result cell for Name enter formula:

```
=SUM(IF(ISBLANK(B2:B9),0,1))
```

the result cell for Response Received enter formula:

```
=SUM(IF((E2:E9="YES"), 1, 0))
```

(adjust the row range numbers as you need to match the range of the data)

IMPORTANT!

After you enter the formula you MUST press: (CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER)
That activated the array formula. You can confirm that by selecting the formula cell
and you will see curly brackets around, like so:

```
{=SUM(IF((E2:E9="YES"), 1, 0))}
```

Try it.

Comment: I can do that, but I want to use Pivot Table to create a tunnel chart and use slicer to build an interactive dashboard.